# How to grep the content to the new file?

Tags: unix

I need to extract the content to a new file.

I do the following :

```
awk old file | grep -i"key"  | cut -f 2 >new.txt
```

Output :

> grep: Invalid argument

There is a empty new.txt file created but without any content.

Answer (score 0):

Add space after `-i`

```
awk old file | grep -i "key"  | cut -f 2 >new.txt
```

P.S. And why you do not add action of `grep` and `cut` in `awk` logic?

Based on the comments maybe you need something like:

```
awk '/key/ {print $2}' old_file.txt >new.txt
```

(assuming delimiter is space)

Here is one example:

```
# cat a2
key 1
orange 2
cool 3
key 4
# grep key a2 >a2.out
```

or with `awk`

```
awk '/key/ {print}' a2 >a2.out
# cat a2.out
1
4
```

Comment: Is there any better way?I don't know how to apply cur.

Comment: Please define exact awk script and what you need to do (with words)

Comment: I just want to extract two column to the new file. The command do not have any reaction by now.

Comment: Which columns? And you probably want to set only lines which have "key" word inside?

Comment: get the content of the second column and pick the word "key" appear in every line.

Comment: it did not print out the content til now.

Comment: in your example, I want key 1 and key 4 , not just 1 and 4.

Comment: so you do not need only second field, edit my answer